# Save image from URL and make it persist IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, data-persistence

I would like to save images from a URL and then use them inside my app.

I saved them in variables but how can I make them persist until the user deletes the app ?

Here is the code for saving images in variables

```
    let backgroundURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let backgroundData:NSData? = NSData(contentsOf: backgroundURL as! URL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (backgroundData != nil) {
                background = UIImage(data: backgroundData! as Data   
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I save the background image  to persist ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Swift 3

```
// Assuming background is UIImage
if let image = background {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```

That call to getDocumentsDirectory()

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: Thanks Museer Ansari!

Comment: @MikeMe Welcome bro :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store image in your document directory the below code you will be able to use after you downloaded image and converted as UIImage from NSData

**Swift 2.3**

```
let documentsDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
// Name of Image you want to store
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("ImageName.jpg")

if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL.path!) {
    if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToFile(fileURL.path!, atomically: true) {
        print("Image saved")
    } else {
        print("error saving Image")
    }
} else {
    print("Image name already exists")
}
```

And here is how you can get image

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("imageName.jpg")

if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imagePAth){
let myImage: UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
}
else{
print("No Such Image")
}
```

Comment: I think in swift 3 `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` will become swift's `Data` so it should be `write(to: fileURL, options:)`?

Comment: Yeah I should have mention in answer this is syntax for swift 2.3

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Swift 5?